# Can I use kotlin "also" function just to shorten the code?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, readability

Do kotlin docs say anything about using the `also()` function just to reduce code lines? I mean doing some unrelated work in the lambda body and not using the `it` parameter.

For example instead of this:

```kotlin
fun togglePeriod() {
    viewModel.togglePeriod()
    showStatistics()
}
```

I've written this:

```
fun togglePeriod() = viewModel.togglePeriod().also { showStatistics() }
```

Comment: I wouldn't hide unrelated side effects there like that.

Comment: The return type won't be the same, so it is not as harmless as it could seem.

Comment: [This article](https://elizarov.medium.com/with-the-receiver-in-scope-7b52bdcca6e9#:~:text=For%20general-purpose%20needs%20rely%20on%20Kotlin%20scope%20functions%20with%2C%20run%2C%20apply.%20Their%20use%20is%20idiomatic%20in%20Kotlin.%20However%2C%20resist%20the%20urge%20to%20use%20them%20just%20to%20make%20your%20code%20shorter.) recommends not using these functions just to shorten the code.

Answer (score 3):

The code should be readable and express the intention. Reducing the line count for the sake of reducing line count rarely results in the readability improvement.

If toggling a period should result in displaying statistics it makes perfect sense to have a separate `togglePeriod()` method body, it shows the intention nicely. `also()` doesn't feel as readable.

Comment: Agreed.  Clarity and readability is usually more important than brevity.  Sometimes, those things go together; here, I don't think they do, so separate lines would be better.  Also, showing stats in a method called `togglePeriod()` seems confusing in itself!  I'd suggest either renaming it to `togglePeriodAndShowStats()`, or keeping the two separate.